# Alcance de variable en evento onfocus de un Input

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, ionic2

Estoy trabajando con ionic 2 y tengo una variable que quiero acceder en un evento en mi código html, pero por consola me sale indefinida, ¿Como hago para tener alcance a dicha variable?

**Código ts:**

```
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-productos',
  templateUrl: 'productos.html',
})
export class Productos {
  nItemCart = 14;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }
ionViewDidLoad() {
    //console.log('ionViewDidLoad Productos');
  }
}
```

**Código html:**

```
<input type="number" name="miinput" min="0" max="50" onfocus="console.log(nItemCart)" [(ngModel)]="producto.cantidad">
```

**Resultado por Consola:**

```
undefined
```

Comment: Tendrías que ponerlo afuera de cualquier función, evento, clase u objeto que no sea la clase misma donde la estás declarando, para que quede en un ámbito global, ya que si pones el código en fiddle funciona sin ningún tipo de referencia. https://jsfiddle.net/lixusrarnavo/y5njzs4y/

Comment: puedes darme un ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien tu pregunta quieres acceder a `nItemCart` en el momento que enfoques (focus) el input. Para eso puedes usar el evento [(focus)](https://angular.io/guide/user-input) de Angular 2:

[Ver Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/6pTWXHaReVId22dl5to7/)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input type="number" 
           min="0" 
           max="50" 
           (focus)="itemCart()">  
  `,
})
export class App {

  nItemCart:number = 0;

  constructor() {

    this.nItemCart = 1234;
  }

  itemCart() {
    console.log(this.nItemCart);
  }
}
```